# How to process the elements excluding the one selected in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I process the elements that are not currently selected.
Ex. on my html file, I have

```
<table>
  <tr><td> .... </tr></td>
  <tr><td> .... </tr></td>
  <tr><td> .... </tr></td>
  <tr><td> .... </tr></td>
</table>
```

on js file,
I have a click event and choose one of the row. During this event trigger, I'd like to process the other rows.

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
   // process the unselected rows here such as change the background color...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [siblings function](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings#expr).

Then it would be in the click function:

```
$(this).siblings();
```

Comment: Pretty straight forward. I never saw this in the Jquery.com document

Answer (score 0):

+1 on [fphilipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439013/how-to-process-the-elements-excluding-the-one-selected-in-jquery/1439045#1439045), though there is the thing that the logic of the styles should be inverted - i.e. you should style the selected row, rather than processing the other rows.

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .siblings().removeClass('selected').end()
        .addClass('selected');
});
```

And the CSS

```
.selected { background-color: #D6E4EE; }
```